# "The bot's Microsoft App ID or Microsoft App Password is incorrect." after following Steps to Add Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, botframework

### Version

4.14.1

### Describe the bug

Follow the steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

The memory bot works well with emulator.

After adding changes to use Cosmos DB from same tutorial, the code runs fine,
However  emulator states
`{ "message": "The bot's Microsoft App ID or Microsoft App Password is incorrect.", "status": 400 }`

The app id and password is exactly same as in appsettings.json.

### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Follow Steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp
   and run the bot with Cosmos DB
2. Start Emulator and Input URL, Microsoft App ID, Microsoft App Password (App ID and Password to be exactly same as in appsettings.json)
3. error "The bot's Microsoft App ID or Microsoft App Password is incorrect." is observed.

### Expected behavior

The Emulator would connect to bot process.

### Screenshots

[image]

[bug]

Answer (score 0):

Workaround Fix: Use v4.18.1 of "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure" and not the latest version.